# Create custom content type and set up fields by module

Tags: image, drupal, field

I'm working on a custom module and I would like to definiate a custom node type with some fields like image field. I don't like to use features it is great module but I don't like to use it. My question is that where I can find some information about for example the image field spexial settings?

```
'job_post_image' => array(
  'field_name' => 'job_post_image',
  'label' => $t('Images related to this job post.'),
  'type' => 'image',
  'cardinality' => -1,
  ??? what are the more options? For example file path, alt tag and etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wouldn't use the Features module for this. Your use case is exactly why that module exists. Even though you don't want to use the module in production, you might want to create your content type and export it as a feature to examine the code to see how it is all put together.

There is also a pretty comprehensive look at creating an image field programatically at https://www.drupal.org/node/1044248.

Comment: You are right but I would like to learn what happened behind the scenes.

Comment: Then I think the link I posted to drupal.org will give you a detailed look at the structure of an imagefield. Are you looking to go deeper than that? If so, looking at the code for imagefield would be a good start.